# How to automount hdd without causing freeze when missing?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I used to add external usb hdds as automounts in `/etc/fstab`, but sometimes I remove them (or they fail) rebooting the server fails since they won't mount.

Is there a way to automount system hdds if they exist, but don't hold up the boot process if they're not there?

It is absolutely imperative that the machine be able to reboot properly because I can't physically access it easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount an external drive at boot time only if it is plugged in](http://askubuntu.com/q/14365/65969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TrailRider](https://askubuntu.com/users/65969/trailrider)'s link provided a starting point, but using the fstab options [`auto, nofail, defaults`](http://www.eazynet.de/nofail_option_in_etc_fstab) will achieve the wanted behavior.

Comment: `nofail` was never implemented; [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/610869) has been around for at least three years.

Comment: Did not work in Raspbian 11 with nofail and nobootwait.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to skip fstab. Install `autofs` and configure your external disks to be mounted when you need them.

Comment: Couldn't get autofs to work with an ntfs hdd.

Answer (score -1):

try to mount your external drive by uuid

something like this in your etc/fstab :

```
UUID=7CB8A6BAB8A671F6 /media/USBdisk ext3 defaults 0 0
```

plug your external USB drive and type'sudo blkid' on console to know your UUID.

Don't forget to 'sudo mkdir /media/USBdisk && chown my_pseudo:my_pseudo /media/USBdisk' before reboot.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question. This will still delay boot.